# is it possible to do some custom logic when the rust diesel insert conflict(not update)

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

Now I am using this rust `cargo 1.69.0 (6e9a83356 2023-04-12)` diesel `diesel = { version = "2.0.4", features = ["postgres","64-column-tables","chrono","serde_json"] }` code to insert some record like this:

```
use crate::common::database::get_connection;
use crate::diesel::RunQueryDsl;
use crate::model::article::add_article::AddArticle;
use crate::model::diesel::dolphin::custom_dolphin_models::Article;
use crate::diesel::OptionalExtension;

pub fn insert_article(input_article: &AddArticle) -> Result<Option<Article>, diesel::result::Error> {
    use crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::article::dsl::*;
    let result = diesel::insert_into(article)
        .values(input_article)
        .on_conflict_do_nothing()
        .get_result(&mut get_connection())
        .optional();
    return result;
}
```

this code works fine, but now I want to store the article to redis when the record conflict. is it possible to do like that? I have read the master branch document from here https://docs.diesel.rs/master/diesel/upsert/struct.IncompleteOnConflict.html seems impossible to do some custom logic when conflict happen(only support do update).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conflict logic doesn't do anything in the database so there's no reason for Diesel to support it. Instead of telling your database to silently ignore conflicts, just do the insert and let it return an error. You would get back a [`Error::DatabaseError`](https://docs.diesel.rs/master/diesel/result/enum.Error.html) with [`DatabaseErrorKind::UniqueViolation`](https://docs.diesel.rs/master/diesel/result/enum.DatabaseErrorKind.html) if there was a conflict and you can detect that and do your own logic afterwards.